# How to put name in each of the filename in the x axis box graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run my code to view the box graph, I noticed that the x-axis of the plot don't have filename in it instead showing 1,2,3,4,5,6.....

This is the code I'm working for now

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

folder_path = "path to image folder"

# Get a list of the TIFF image in the folder
tiff_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.tiff')]

# Loop through the images in the folder
grey_values = []
for img_file in tiff_files:
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(folder_path, img_file))
    grey_values.append(np.asarray(img).ravel())

# Plot the grey values as a box graph
plt.boxplot(grey_values)
plt.title('Grey Values of TIFF Images')
plt.xlabel('Image')
plt.ylabel('Grey Value')
plt.show()
```

I have tried add "Label=tiff_files" but it throw errors and kind of clueless how to put filename instead of normal numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) function

Here is an example (working with `.png` file in my case)

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.boxplot(grey_values)

# Set xticks, requires values and labels
xticks_range = range(1, len(tiff_files) + 1)
plt.xticks(xticks_range ,labels=tiff_files, rotation=45, ha="right")

plt.title('Grey Values of TIFF Images')
plt.xlabel('Image')
plt.ylabel('Grey Value')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that if you decide to design your figure using axis method, you can directly use `ax.set_xticklabels` function